# what is the definition of $\dot{H^1}$

Tags: notation, sobolev-spaces

In this paper: [Duyckaerts-Kenig-Merle](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0365.pdf) there is a symbol $\dot{H^1}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ with a dot over $H^1$, anyone know the definition of this symbol?

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059192/sobolev-space-notation

Comment: It is the homogeneous version of the Sobolev space, with norm the norm of the gradient in $L^2$, and a condition such as "vanishing to $0$ at infinity

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: For background on this kind of mathematics I recommend the book of Bahouri-Chemin-Danchin.